# How to move blob data to another table?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, blob

I have stored my images in my database using blob data type, and I want to transfer it to another table. I am using vb.net. do you guys have any idea on how to transfer this blob files to another table using mysql?

Comment: is this something you want to do one time? Or something you want to do over and over inside your application?

Comment: i want to do over and over inside my application sir. i want to move the specific data blob using comlumn_id and move to another table. do you have idea on how to move the blob data to another table sir? can you help me?

Comment: I imagine some kind of `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query using a `SELECT` from the source table would do the job, but consider redesigning your tables. Have an `images` table containing the `BLOB` images and a primary key, and then have other tables use a foreign key to the `images` table. This would be much, much, much more efficient as then you would only need to update the foreign key IDs on the other tables. Or you might consider some kind of status column on the `images` table if that would do the job. In other words, moving blobs is probably expensive. Avoid it.

Comment: thank you jpmc26 it gives me clue on how to solve this problem. ill try what you've said to me

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the next SQL statement would work. Have you tried anything similar?

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable BlobField SELECT BlobField FROM SourceTable
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: thank you Pantelis Natsiavas, but this query is not working. i very much appreciated your help :)

Comment: when you say it is not working, what do you mean? Do you get an error? No need to say that you should change the `TargetTable`, `SourceTable` and `BlobField` with your specific schema structures.